# eclipse repaint editor screen (~= vi ctrl-L)

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

My eclipse regularly displays yellow pop-ups with reference-info about code (more often than I would care).  Unfortunately, sometimes portions of the pop-ups remain on the screen after I move my mouse.

The current workaround is to scroll the code (and pop-up remains) up off the screen, and back down.  **Is there a command/key-sequence in eclipse to force a screen repaint/refresh?**  The equivalent in vi (or ViM) is the `ctrl-L` key sequence.

Development environment is GNU/Linux (Debian stable) workstation |
eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2 Build id: 20120216-1857 |
java version "1.7.0_05"

Comment: You've probably been hit by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283035/rendering-of-buttons-with-images-in-eclipse-kepler-is-broken/27292432#27292432

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283035/rendering-of-buttons-with-images-in-eclipse-kepler-is-broken/27292432#27292432 for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had that problem, too.  The only way I've been able to clear the popups is by using the up or down arrow key to move the cursor through the affected lines.  That causes a line-by-line refresh.

Comment: Thx - the arrow-line scroll is yet another approach around this problem (though I'm still seeking a key-sequence to repaint ;)).