# Rendering of buttons with images in Eclipse Kepler is broken

Tags: eclipse, button, swt, rendering, eclipse-kepler

With Kepler, the buttons in the Console view are sometimes rendered like this:

[image]

when it should look like this:

[image]

Moving once over the buttons with the mouse fixes the problem. Any idea what could be causing this?

Versions:

- Eclipse Kelper SR1 (20130919-0819)
- Linux Kubuntu 13.04 raring
- libgtk2.0-bin: 2.24.17-0ubuntu2

Comment: Which OS is that? I've been having that issue with Eclipse on Linux for some time now.

Comment: @Baz: there is an eclipse bug concerning menus on Ubuntu: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330563, with various suggestions how to work around the issue.

Comment: @Calon Not using Ubuntu and Unity, but thanks.

Comment: @Baz: Sorry, completely forgot about that :-( Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the various issues seen with Kubuntu, knowing that oxygen-gtk is the default, you could consider checking if the problem persists when [switching to QtCurve](https://askubuntu.com/a/194512/5470).

See for instance:

- [bug 348059](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348059):

> When I change this to "QtCurve" (not installed by default) the buttons are correctly drawn with transparent background. Only during mouse-over a button is raised and gets a gray background.

- [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/441187/):

> I, too, found some bugs which happen only with the gtk theme (`oxygen-gtk` to be precise), and switched to `qtcurve` long ago. No complaints from this front since then.

- [bug 367603](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367603):

> Kubuntu 11.10
>
> - works OK with 11.04
>     Application Appearance : GTK+ Appearance : Widget style: oxygen-gtk
> - works OK with Raleigh (plain ugly) and QtCurve (not installed by default)

---

However, the [OP Aaron Digulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34088/aaron-digulla) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283035/rendering-of-buttons-with-images-in-eclipse-kepler-is-broken/22698114#comment34823905_22698114):

> SWT always relies on Gtk to load the theme (you can't select QtCurve in the appearance prefs page).

Also note that you probably want the Gtk2 based theme for Eclipse (see the blog post "[GNOME (et al): Rotting In Threes](https://igurublog.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/gnome-et-al-rotting-in-threes/)" for reasons).

Comment: I installed `qtcurve` but Eclipse e4 seems to use Gtk3. Is there a package which contains the QtCurve theme for Gtk3?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I thought Eclipse, since Juno (June 2012) was working with QtCurve directly (as shown in http://hwellmann.blogspot.fr/2012/06/fixing-editor-tab-fonts-in-eclipse-juno.html)

Comment: Okay, I found an answer to my question: https://igurublog.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/gnome-et-al-rotting-in-threes/ ... sad :-(

Comment: No, SWT always relies on Gtk to load the theme (you can't select QtCurve in the appearance prefs page).

Comment: @AaronDigulla Ok. I have added your conclusion to the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: so you found a reason for the problem in the "Rotting in Threes" blog, but did it lead to a fix (other than moving the mouse over the buttons)?

Comment: @Harald: No. No one seems to bother or interested to fix the themes, as far as I can tell. You're welcome to open new bugs or comment to the existing ones; maybe you can move something.

Answer (score 1):

Various rendering bugs are discussed in this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333965

The solution is starting Eclipse with

```
GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 ...path.to../eclipse.exe
```

or

```
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1
...path.to../eclipse.exe
```